# Programmatically alter views exposed form option value

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with an exposed form, i need to programmatically change the value of the 'autosubmit' option in code but cant find out how to access it/change it.

The field is defined in the ::options_form method of the views_plugin_exposed_form class, i would like to alter this setting in a hook_views_pre_view() hook or similar but cant find a way to do it currently.

Comment: Please specify your Drupal version as not all the hooks are the same for Drupal 8 and 7.

Comment: Sorry, this is for drupal 7